# My code does double entries into the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I have a code to send information into a table in a database. the code is as bellow;

```
<?php
//session_start();
include("config.php");

$alertcityname = $_POST['city'];
$alerareaname = $_POST['area'];
$email = $_POST['emailid'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$pref = $_POST['alert'];


    $insertQuery = "insert into fir_forward (username,town,area,email,phone,pref)
                     values ('".$_SESSION['username']."','".$alertcityname."','".$alerareaname."',
                     '".$email."','".$phone."','".$pref."')";


     $msg = base64_encode("Registered Successfully");


    mysql_query($insertQuery) or die("error in insert record");

    if(mysql_query($insertQuery))
     {
          header("location:updatemess.php?msg=$msg");     
     }
    else
     {
        header("location:noupdatemess.php?msg=Not Registered");
     }


?>
```

my problem is that data is entered twice or doubles and the table ends up as bellow;

```
F_id            username        townarea        phone           pref    email
0000000001      0000000001 [->] 0000000009 [->] 0000725954499   sms hezragumbe@gmail.com
0000000002      0000000001 [->] 0000000009 [->] 0000725954499   sms hezragumbe@gmail.com
0000000003      0000000003 [->] 0000000002 [->] 0000734566778   email   mildred.achieng@yahoo.ca
0000000004      0000000003 [->] 0000000002 [->] 0000734566778   email   mildred.achieng@yahoo.ca
```

Could somebody kindly assist and make me see the error.

Comment: The fun part of this question is when I read the question, I knew i must look for two times the function: mysql_query. Think about that ;)

Comment: @Pakspul - Lolz.. It clearly Seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are running `mysql_query()` twice. Remove one instance.

```
//mysql_query($insertQuery) or die("error in insert record"); //<---- Comment this

    if(mysql_query($insertQuery))
     {
          header("location:updatemess.php?msg=$msg");     
     }
    else
```

**`Sidenote`**

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Answer (score 0):

Use exit(); after inserting data.

```
 if(mysql_query($insertQuery))
     {
       header("location:updatemess.php?msg=$msg"); 
       exit();        
     }
```

and also you can modify it like this and check if variables are set.

```
 if(isset($alertcityname ) && isset($alerareaname ) && isset($email ) && isset($alertcityname ) && isset($phone)&& isset($pref ) )
    {

          if(mysql_query($insertQuery))
                 {

                      header("location:updatemess.php?msg=$msg"); 
                     exit();    
                 }

        }
```

Comment: i removed one instance as suggested by Shankar and it worked, Great